# Monitoring all running process using strace in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, strace

I want to monitor all the running processes using `strace` and when a process ends the output of the `strace` should be sent to a file.

And how to find every running proc PID. I also want to include process name in the output file.

Comment: "I want to monitor _all_ the running processes using `strace` ..." No, you don't. Really. If only because running `strace` creates a new process, which you would then attempt to monitor, which would start another process, which ... But there are other significant reasons this is a bad idea, as well. You might need to refine your definition of what you need to accomplish a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$  sudo strace -p 1725 -o firefox_trace.txt

$ tail -f firefox_trace.txt
```

1725 would be the PID of the proccess you want to monitor (you can find the PID with "ps -C firefox-bin", for firefox in the example)

And firefox_trace.txt would be the output file !

The way to got would be to find every running proc PID, and use the command to write them in the output file !

---

Considering the [doc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), 
-p pid

> Attach to the process with the process ID pid and begin tracing. The
>   trace may be terminated at any time by a keyboard interrupt signal (
>   CTRL -C). strace will respond by detaching itself from the traced
>   process(es) leaving it (them) to continue running. Multiple -p options
>   can be used to attach to up to 32 processes in addition to command
>   (which is optional if at least one -p option is given).

Comment: How to find every running proc PID.  I also want to include process name in the output file.

Comment: @R.Anu Can't verify right now, but I believe "ps aux" should get you the full procs list... Then try to cut it with a regex or something, to get a list of proc's PID !

Answer (score 0):

Use `-o` to store the output to the file, or `2>&1` to redirect standard error to output, so you can filter it (`grep`) or redirect it into file (`> file`).

To monitor process without knowing its PID, but name, you can use `pgrep` command, e.g.

```
strace -p $(pgrep command) -o file.out
```

where `command` is your name of process (e.g. `php`, `Chrome`, etc.).

To learn more about parameters, check [`man strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).